# How to draw hierarchical clustering?

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
data<-data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4),Y=c(1,3,2,1))
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){ data[i,i]<-NA}
colnames(data) <- c("A","B","C","D")
rownames(data) <- c("A","B","C","D")
plot(hclust(dist(data)))
```

and then the result is the below image:

[image]

But, **I am wondering how this plot is drawn.** Here, I am trying to obtain the dendrogram step by step. We know that the distance matrix at the begining is as follow:

[image]

**Every time we find the two points with minimum distance, and then merge them as a single cluster**

[image]

So, the first merge are B, and C.And we update the distance matrix

[image]

Again we find the 2 points with minimum distance, which is `D` with cluster of `B,C`

[image]

Again we update the distance matrix

[image]

As a result I should have the following merges

1. B, and C
2. B,C, and D
3. B,C,D, and A

But here the is a paradox with what `R` plot produced. So, how do you justify it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Updated Response - Using `single` linkage rather than the default `complete` linkage.

I'll do my best to explain how I see this working. I believe this is as simple as the `method` argument used in `hclust.` The default method for `hclust` does not follow the algorithm that you laid out but we can adjust the `method` so it does.

But first, I am getting an error on the plot you are trying to make:

```
> data<-data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4),Y=c(1,3,2,1))
> for(i in 1:nrow(data)){ data[i,i]<-NA}
> colnames(data) <- c("A","B","C","D")
> rownames(data) <- c("A","B","C","D")
> plot(hclust(dist(data)))
Error in hclust(dist(data)) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)
```

What is your intention with the `for(i in 1:nrow(data)){ data[i,i]<-NA}` line? After that line, your `data` object looks like this:

```
   X  Y V3 V4
1 NA  1 NA NA
2  2 NA NA NA
3  3  2 NA NA
4  4  1 NA NA
```

However, if we can just start with the following code, we can generate the desired tree as follows:

```
dt<-data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Y = c(1, 3, 2, 1))
rownames(dt) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
dt<-dist(dt)
plot(hclust(dt, method = "single"))
```

[image]

NOTE the change in `method` on the `hclust` call to `method = single`. The default `method` is `method = complete`. The `complete` linkage method does **not** join clusters to nodes based on the *shortest* distance but on the *longest* intercluster distance. Extracting some material from the fantastic [Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/%7Egareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf) which describes the various linkage methods available:

[image]

This text, by James, Witten, Hastie, and Tibshirani, is available as a free download at the link above. The section on hierarchical clustering starts on page 390. Please let me know if this helps clear things up.

## Original Response

I think you are calling the `dist` function in the wrong manner and perhaps too many times. Try this:

```
dt<-data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4),Y=c(1,3,2,1))
rownames(dt) <- c("A","B","C","D")
dt<-dist(dt)
plot(hclust((dt)))
```

[image]

Effectively, you were calling `dist` on an object which was already a class of `dist` that you then turned into a matrix and then called `dist` on again within your call to `plot`.

We can examine just the distance object as follows:

```
> dt
         A        B        C
B 2.236068                  
C 2.236068 1.414214         
D 3.000000 2.828427 1.414214
```

There is no need to call `dist` on this object again before passing it to the `hclust` function.

Comment: @Salman, thank you for providing additional clarification on your question. I have updated my response to include an explanation of the linkage type in the `hclust` function which can be specified with the `method` argument. Using a different `method` besides the default one can result in the outcome you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer